# Question about closed subalgebras

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras

I'm trying to understand the following statement.

Let $C = C(T)$ the collection of all continuous maps from the unit circle $T \subset \mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{C}$, and let $A$ be the algebra of all continuous maps on the closed unit disk $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ which are analytic on $\text{Int} \: D$.

Define the map $\varphi: A \longrightarrow C$ by $\varphi(f) = f|_{T}$.  Then $\varphi$ is a unital homomorphism onto the closed subalgebra $B$ of $C$ generated by the set $\{1,z\} \subset C$ for $1$ the unit map and $z$ the inclusion function.

My question, why is $B \neq C$?  $B$ is the linear span of $1$ and $z$ right? So it seems to me by the Stone Weirstrass theorem that since $B$ is the closure of the collection of polynomials of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k z^k$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) should give you $C=C(T)$.

Is $B \subset C$ properly?  If so, why?  Thank you.

Comment: $\left. \frac{1}{z} \right|_T \in C$, but no holomorphic function (functions having the power series you write) restrict to that element of $C$ on $T$.  (That map in $C$ is  conjugation: $z \mapsto \overline{z}$, which is [antiholomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function).  It's continuous, so is in $A$, but it's not in the span of $\{1,z\}$.)

Comment: Great, thank you.  Quick follow up question, They go on to say the spectrum of $z: T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in B is D, which doesn't make sense to me, since isn't $\lambda - z = 0$ only true for $\lambda \in T$, since thats the domain of z?

Comment: @Isochron First, $B$ is not the linear span of $\{1,z\}$, but the algebra generated by these functions. Second, please ask a new question instead of posting follow-ups in the comments.

Comment: @MaoWao thank you, I'll do that in the future.  You comment confuses me however, the linear span of $\{1,z\}$ is surely the smallest subalgebra containing the two functions, so isn't the closure of the linear span equal to B?  How would B be anything else?

Comment: @Isochron The linear span is not a subalgebra. $B$ is the set of all polynomials, not just linear-affine ones.